# Bootstrap calculations without the Statistics Toolbox

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to use the bootstrap technique in MATLAB without using Statistics toolbox.

My data set is a 2 x 50 matrix, with column 1 being months, and column 2 precip. values. I calculated the mean, std deviation, and skewness coefficient using this script:

```
yr = x(:,1);
p = x(:,2);
x_hat = mean(p);
sd = p-x_hat;
s = sqrt((1/(n-1)) .* (sum((sd).^2)));
skew = ((1/(n-1)) .* (sum((sd).^3))/(s.^3));
```

I need to b) loop over the number of bootstrap calculations I want (10000), and with that loop k,

c) randomly select a subset of N values from the original data (suggested doing using the random number generator multiplied by N, then rounded to give an integer).

Once I have N,
d) I will calculate (and store) desired statistic for each k,

e) sort the stored vector from lowest to highest,

f) and then find the value that cuts off the lowest 0.025 and the highest 0.025.

Any advice at all would be great.

Comment: try to post an actual programming or language problem, instead of a series of related or unrelated assignment tasks. From your post, I understand that your problem is how to draw random samples from a dataset stored as a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to drawing random samples from `[1, N]`, where N the sample number you need for each trial. You then index the columns of your data matrix directly using k different permutations. Example (Samples = 50, Trials = 1000, Subset = 40):

```
x = randn(2, 50); % example data matrix
N = 50; nTrials = 1000; nSamples = 40;
```

To generate samples without repetition, or *sampling without replacement*, you can use [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) which calls`rand`.

```
for k = 1:nTrials
  indexSample(:,k) = randperm(N, nSamples);      
end
```

If you want *sampling with replacement* (i.e. for bootstrap) replace the call to `randperm` with:

```
indexSample(:,k) = round(N*rand(nSamples, 1))
```

and increase nSamples accordingly.

The data sample set for each trial (e.g. k = 1), is then:

```
xk = x(:, indexSample(:,k)) % sample data for trial k
```